# check in .cs page and displaying in .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my .cs page i want to check some condition and depending on that i will show/hide a div in my .aspx page. Is that possible?

like

```
if(j==0)
{
div id="hi".visible=false; //something like that
}
```

I hope u guys understood the problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.aspx.cs

```
if (j == 0)
{
  hi.visible = false;
}
```

.aspx

```
<div id="hi" runat="server"></div>
```

Please note, the "runat" sttribute is the important part. This allows it to be accessed in the .cs file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `runat="server"` to the <div> in the .aspx page and then you can access it directly in your code behind. Like so:

Page.aspx:

```
<!-- ... -->
<div id="hi" runat="server">
  Content Here
</div>
<!-- ... -->
```

Page.aspx.cs:

```
// ...

if (j == 0)
{
    hi.Visible = false;
}

//...
```